# Probability of winning if I get queen of hearts as 2nd card?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a question from *Statistics* by Freedman, Pisani, and Purves:
[image]

I don't understand the way that the textbook did the problem. Why is it not (51/52)*(1/51) since 
1. the card drawing is w/o replacement,
2. the first card can't be queen of hearts else its impossible for the second card to be queen of hearts. So the probability of the first card has to be 51/52

I know the textbook answer comes out to is also 1/52 but I don't understand their reasoning.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Both answers, the one in the book, and the one in OP based on the two level tree model "$(51/52)\cdot (1/52)$" come to the same probability. The tree level works best for the beginning. The solution in the book says that for the uniform finite probability space of all permutations of $\Omega=\{1,2,\dots , 52\}$ for an element $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{52})$ we have $  P(x_1=Q\heartsuit)=P(x_2=Q\heartsuit)$. Because the map $(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)\to(x_2,x_1,x_3,\dots)$ switching the first two "cards" is preserving the measure.

Answer (score 1):

For part a)

Each position is equally probable for the well shuffled deck.  So Queen Hearts being in  second (or any) position is 1/52.

part b)

Although initially it was still 1/52, after seeing the first card the probability is now 1/51 (one in remaining 51 cards).

Answer (score 0):

"Why is it not (51/52)*(1/51) since 1. the card drawing is w/o replacement"

If you do this calculation, you will find that your solutions is also correct (51/52)*(1/51) = (51*1)/(51*52) = (1/52). Your instinct to solve this problem is correct, the book just explains it in a different manner.